# search mifare tag 1K with Key B

Tags: mifare

I can read and write with key A and set this code for sector trailer:

```
44 11 00 03 22 11 FF 07 80 69 44 11 00 03 22 11
```

I can read with key A  but can not read with Key B and Display this message:

```
468: Authentication KEY (OK--0x00)
469: Read Card (ERROR -->Auth error --0x05)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FF 07 80 is the default Access Conditions. Key A is set as master key with full access rights and key B is disabled.

Here you have more Access Conditions:
http://www.gorferay.com/sector-trailer-and-access-conditions/

Set 78 77 88 FF if you want key A for reading only and key B for writing and reading.
E.g.: AA AA AA AA AA AA 78 77 88 FF BB BB BB BB BB BB

Hope this helps you.